# Sum Matrix cell, sub total not working, footer not working

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a matrix with several groups(employees, managers and departments). I have columns: sum time expected, sum time entered, sum overtime, sum missing time. At the manager and department level the overtime and missing time skew the results. Basically if a manager has two employees and one has 5 hrs overtime and the other has 5 hrs missing time, the result will show that for the manager there is no overtime or missing time for their employees.. I have tried to add subtotals but I get the same outcome. I have also tried to =sum(textbox.value) but I get the error that aggregates on textboxes have to be within footers. I believe that subtotal rows should be considered footers but that is not the case. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Time Expected   Time Reported    OT     MISSING-------------------------------------------------------------------
Total by Manager----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
80 ------------------                 80 ---------------          0  ------    0--------

Totals by Employee---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
40    --------------------              35     --------------   0--------           5---------
-----------------------------------------------------------------40     --------------------             45       --------------    5    --------0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527441/ssrs-total-from-sub-group-to-parent-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my problem. My calculations were thrown because I had tried to use isnothing to replace NaN with 0s.